# DDA algorithm for all quadrants

Tags: java

i was wondering how can I edit this DDA.
When I have this values: (x1 = 150,y1 = 20,x2 = 100,y2 = 80) it works perfectly fine, because it is in first quadrant.

But if I want to rasterize line from another qudrant

- for example with value of (x1 = 10,y1 = 20,x2 = 100,y2 = 80)
- this will make just straight line

So I'm having trouble with editing this algorithm to all 4 quadrants.

```
public void rasterize(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color) {
        int x, y, krok;
        float dy, dx;
        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;

        if(Math.abs(dx)>Math.abs(dy)){
            krok=(int)(Math.abs(dx));
        } else {
            krok=(int)(Math.abs(dy));
        }
        dx = dx / (float)krok;
        dy = dy/ (float)krok;
        x=x1;
        y=y1;
        for(int i=1;i<=krok;i++){
            raster.setPixel(x, y, 0xffff00);
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you copy and pasted the same values twice into your question. According to your question `(x1 = 150,y1 = 20,x2 = 100,y2 = 80)` will both work "perfectly fine" but also doesn't work and just make a straight line....which makes no sense to me

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed type the value of x1... it should be OK now